# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor) Android

Tags: java, android, json, url, socketexception

I try to read json file from the URL in my Android Project. But strange situation happens. StringBuilder successfully gets first few characters but then I get java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Why I get this exception?

What is wrong with my code?)

JSON: http://inlyfortesting.ucoz.net/artists.json

My JSONParser:

```
    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String urlAsString) {
        // try to create JSONObject from string
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAsString);
            new DownloadFileTask().execute(url).get();
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj;
    }

    private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
        StringBuilder sb;
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
                is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            //file reading
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                int symbol;
                int counter = 0;
                while ((symbol = reader.read()) != -1) { //PROBLEM HERE
                    sb.append((char)symbol); //OR HERE
                }
                json = sb.toString();
                is.close();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `connection.disconnect();`. Remove that. If you are disconnected you cannot read any more as you are trying to do now.

Comment: `new DownloadFileTask().execute(url).get();`. Very bad programming to call the .get() method there. Remove the get() and place the following statement in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 5):

You're disconnecting the connection before you read from it. You need to do that afterwards.

Surely this is obvious?